# How to implement CommonTree class in ANTLR4

Tags: javascript, node.js, antlr4

### What I want to realize: Treating comment by ANTLR4 in JavaScript

Now I'm coding interpret C script by antlr4js, and I want to take comment content.
example:

```
/* this is my function */
int add(int a, int b);
```

then, I want get string `"this is my function"`, and attach to `add()`.

I googled and found that I can use `hidden channel`.
Here is the page that I refer to :

[This is Stuff: Tackling Comments in ANTLR Compiler](http://meri-stuff.blogspot.com/2012/09/tackling-comments-in-antlr-compiler.html)

I can code collecting comment after lexing (describing at Collecting Hidden Tokens in above page), but I can't follow next section Merging Tokens With AST because I can't find out CommonTree class what base class.

### problem point

The image to code.(in above page)

```
public class HiddenTokenAwareTree extends CommonTree {

  private List<Token> preceding = new LinkedList<Token>();
  private List<Token> orphans = new LinkedList<Token>();
  private List<Token> following = new LinkedList<Token>();

  // ... constructors, getters and setters follow

}
```

This is Java code, so when implement in javascript, code will be like this:

```
var CommonTree = require("antlr4/PATH/TO/COMMONTREE").CommonTree;

class HiddenTokenAwareTree{

}
```

I can't find out this `PATH/TO/COMMONTREE`.

### my project setting

node: 6.14.6
$ npm list --depth=0
├── antlr4@4.8.0
├── webpack@4.44.1
└── webpack-cli@3.3.12
I installed antlr4 by $ npm i antlr4.

Thanks for any advices !

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you're linking to is for ANTLR v3, ANTLR v4 doesn't have the ability to define a custom tree adapter.

What you could do is create a [visitor](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md#how-do-i-create-and-run-a-visitor) or [listener](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md#how-do-i-create-and-run-a-custom-listener) and retrieve hidden tokens at certain nodes in your parse tree.

Comment: Thanks for your advice ! Now I googled again and found [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752817/how-can-i-detect-whitespace-in-my-parse-tree-in-antlr4) then I can treat comment, thanks !